# actionscript 3 - x/y coordinates of a random array element

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random

I basically have a bunch of enemies in my game stored in an array while they are alive. I want a friendly ship to pick a random target from the array of enemies and shoot it. For this I need the x and y coordinates of that randomly selceted enemy from the array as it is used in the following calculation for the bullets:

```
_endX = randomenemyship.x - 50 * _pcos + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - _bulletSpread * .5;
_endY = randomenemyship.y  - 50 * _psin + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - _bulletSpread * .5;
```

Would anyone be able  to help, Ive been looking at how to select a random array element but Im not sure how to get coordinates and use it in a calculation like above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To select a random element and get the x and y coordinates of it, you would do something like this:

```
var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
trace(rand.x, rand.y);
// rand.x and rand.y are the coordinates
```

As for the calculation, make your own and try not to copy code directly from the internet and you will know where the following values get placed in it.